# Use Identity framework in my entity framework project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to get identity framework to work in my entity framework project.

So far I have created a set of tables and am able to update these via C# code. I now need to get identity framework working so i can link my tables to users.

I have created a context for the identity but keep getting the error:

> The entity type IdentityUser is not part of the model for the current context.

I have created the tables by creating an MVC project as this is the only way i could work out how too.

My context class is as follows:

```
public class SecurityContext : IdentityDbContext
```

I tried to change my default context to inherit from IdentityDbContext but I had the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
namespace LivingstoneWebAPI
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class LivingstoneWebNewEntities : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public LivingstoneWebNewEntities()
            : base("name=Test")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<IPRestriction> IPRestrictions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does your context inherit from `IdentityDbContext` or `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>`?

Comment: And are you remembering to call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` from your `OnModelCreating` override?

Comment: I added my code to the question

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mix ASP.NET Identity with an EDMX based Context.  This is a problem because Identity uses a Code First based context, and this is going to be a lot of problems.